# I turn Landscape page horizontally. So must printer flip on Long or Short Edge?

Tags: printing

When I turn page, I turn horizontally like [this picture](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001037/0001037857/view/printer/unv/0055.htm).

[image]

This means I pick "Flip on short edge" right? Pls see screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly yes, you want the workflow to turn on the short edge.